# zsh history completion with sudo

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

I was wondering if there is a feature where you get history completion (by pressing UP and DOWN) for the command but also for the already entered arguments, this would be really convenient with `sudo`, so for example:

$ sudo vim [PRESSING UP]
--> will complete me to `sudo vim .zshrc` (if this was my last command), but if I [PRESS UP] again I get completion for:
$ sudo ls /
(if this was my penultimate sudo command)

But what I want is completion for commands starting with `sudo vim` only.
I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This is not unique to "sudo"...

Comment: This is a limitation of the function `up-line-or-search`. Open `man zshzle` and search for `up-line-or-search`. This command only uses the first word to search history.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds *similar* to “fish”-like suggestions. Here’s an [implementation for Zsh](https://github.com/tarruda/zsh-autosuggestions). Such things are more often geared towards `tab` or `Ctrl-D` completion than Up-Arrow.

There is also the `predict-on` Zsh widget which will auto-fill your last similar command, as typed so far. Worth experimenting with:

```
% autoload predict-on; predict-on
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the function `up-line-or-search`. Open `man zshzle` and search for `up-line-or-search`. This command only uses the first word to search history.

To get "full line" search on `up`/`down` keys

```
autoload -U up-line-or-beginning-search
autoload -U down-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N down-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[A" up-line-or-beginning-search # Up
bindkey "^[[B" down-line-or-beginning-search # Down
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `history-beginning-search-backward` widget for that. It searches backwards in the history for lines with the same beginning as the current line up to the cursor position. You could replace your current binding or create a new one, for example on <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> (on my machine it maps to `^[[a`):

```
bindkey '^[[a' history-beginning-search-backward
```

You may also want to bind the `history-beginning-search-backward` widget in order to be able to move in both directions through the history (<kbd>ShiftDown</kbd>, `^[[b` on my machine):

```
bindkey '^[[b' history-beginning-search-forward
```